# Remove "Username" and Login URL from Wordpress Registration Mail Content

Tags: wordpress, email, registration

i have question how to remove Username and Login Account URL from Wordpress Registration mail send to member. Example how looks now:

[image]

I want to remove that info from member registration mail that comes currently to all members. I found that function is controlled by this function:

```
wp_new_user_notification_mail()
```

that is contacined in **wp-includes/plugable.php** i found this function also:

```
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );

function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, 
$user, $blogname ) {
$wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = sprintf( '[%s] New user %s 
registered.', $blogname, $user->user_login );
$wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = sprintf( "%s ( %s ) has 
registerd to your blog %s.", $user->user_login, $user->user_email, $blogname );
return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

But seems that dont changing nothing.. I still get default confirmation mail after creating new member account. Any help here?

Comment: Try checking here as it has already been answered - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15304/how-to-change-the-default-registration-email-plugin-and-or-non-plugin

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my question.

```
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 
'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );

function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( 
$wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
$wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = sprintf( '[%s] New user %s 
registered.', $blogname, $user->user_login );
$wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = sprintf( "%s ( %s ) has 
registerd to your blog %s.", $user->user_login, $user->user_email, $blogname 
 );
return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
 }
```